# VWAG TSI engines and intercooler

Tags: turbocharger, skoda, octavia, intercooler

I have a [TSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Volkswagen_Group_petrol_engines#1.4_R4_16v_TSI.2FTFSI) engine but auto is not VW. I wonder if these engines come along with intercooler or is it just oil cooling.

Is there a way of identifiying as I can open the bonnet and notice?

edit: it is 2012 octavia 1.4 tsi 96kw/125hp
in the link I gave it says motor comes with water intercooler but only thing I can recognise is radiator :/

Comment: what year is it?

Comment: But Skoda is a part of the Volkswagen Auto Group, so it _is_  a VW engine, right?

Comment: I mentioned the automobile not the engine. I thought there might be differences between brands in terms of engine specs. etc.

Comment: Don't all modern turbo engines come with an intercooler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly answer your question, yes your car has an inter-cooler. Here is a [link to Forge site](http://www.forgemotorsport.co.uk/VW_Golf_and_SEAT_Leon_18T_Alloy_Side_Mount_Intercooler--product--715.html) to a replacement for your OEM one (this prove the existence of the stock one).

I cannot find any definitive answer but as far as I can tell most (see lower) VW engines with turbos have an inter-cooler. It is generally located behind the bumper on either side of the car (not in front of the radiator) in front of the inner fender. From my own limited experience it is generally on the drivers side of the car (North America), so left side. I don't know how this applies to other models where the driver is on the right side.

I had some time to do some research and it seems some older diesel engines came without an inter-cooler. Also has I have found, from the comment from Paulster2, some cars with transverse engines have the inter-cooler on the right side of the car. I also added a picture of where the inter-cooler is located in a Jetta (on your car it should be approximately the same location on either side).

[image]

Comment: I had a 2004 Jetta 1.8T ... I'm about 99.99% positive it didn't come with an intercooler. It's just one of those things I would have noticed.

Comment: @Paulster2 I'm 100% positive they had an intercooler from factory. Here a link to a mk4 jetta 1.8t were the front bumper is off. I made an arrow to the intercooler. http://s12.postimg.org/b9dv0yx9p/Jetta_OEMIntercooler.jpg

Comment: @Rémi I will check the part you mentioned in my car asap. Hopefully I will recognise things down there.

Comment: @DucatiKiller thank you for the extensive edit :)
I wasn't sure if I should included the picture directly in the answer since it's a jetta with another older engine. Anyway thank you

Comment: @Rémi  - NP, very nice answer  :)

Answer (score 1):

A water cooled intercooler is simple. The intercooler core (where the compressed hot air passes through) is submerged in water from the cooling system (sometimes a separate cooling system). That way the water absorbs the heat and lowers the air's temperature.

The system has various components. For which the locations are near or in front of the radiator and near or in the intake manifold.

For reference:

http://www.enginebasics.com/Advanced%20Engine%20Tuning/Images/Water%20to%20air%20intercooler1.jpg

Comment: Air-2-air is *way more simple* than air-2-water intercooler ... I'm talking *magnitudes* easier. This is in both installation and maintenance.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes, you are right! They are indeed simpler. The water-to-air is used more in applications where packaging is an issue. Or in race applications when there is not a lot of airflow going through the core (drag racing) for long periods of time. Unless you race a porsche 911 and are stuck with the silly intercooler wedged inside the whaletail setup. I've had to work miracles on those cars to get the to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what engine you do have if it's not Volkswagen group and to which vehicle it is fitted.

An intercooler is easy to identify as it will be fitted in the air intake pipework, effectively plumbed into the turbocharger / air filter / throttle body ducting.